# Como traduzir para Inglês "que eu aconselho"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

> There is also an audio sample, [que eu aconselho].

How could I best complete this sentence?
Alternatively, how could I re-structure it to communicate what I mean?

---

I found this alternative, but it does not feel like proper English ("shoot the innacurate").

> - (...) which I suggest you listen to.

Comment: "audio" is not countable, so we wouldn't write "also a sample audio." Either "also sample audio" or "also a sample audio file."

Comment: @Nathaniel you can edit the question if you want.

Comment: @JorgeB. Hmm, it looks like my edits would be less than 6 characters, which prevents my edit from going through.  I'll let ANeves update it if he likes.

Comment: @Nathaniel you are right I will edit the question for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternative you found is okay:

> There is also an audio sample, which I suggest you listen to.

This sounds a bit formal, however, and depending on tone, it can sound a bit pushy.  Some other options include:

> There is also an audio sample, which I recommend.
>   There is also an audio sample, which I hope you'll listen to.

Or, recasting the sentence:

> I recommend the audio sample.
>   I hope you'll listen to the audio sample.

These last two sound the most natural to me on their own, but the others are perfectly valid options if you need to use them.

Comment: I would prefer the last two, but they actually miss the first half of the sentence. (So I went with `which I recommend`.)